# How to create connection on SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

i installed SQL Developer on my MacBook

when i tried to run the sql code it says must create new connection

it required username/password

so how can i solve this

before i was using oracle database XE 12 on windows 10

but now i am using macOS and i see i cant use this software anymore (oracle database XE 12)

so i tried to install SQL Developer

[image: This is what shows to me when i try run the sql code]

Comment: Grab our VirtualBox appliance from OTN https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/

Answer (score 2):

Oracle SQL Developer is a tool that lets you connect to an (Oracle) database. But - you have to have the database as well (apparently, there's none on your Mac).

Express Edition database you previously used on Windows 10 was (probably) 11g (not 12; it doesn't exist), but it woks on Windows an Linux - not macOS.

Moreover, none of the *modern* Oracle databases can be installed on Mac; the last one was, I think, 10g (but - as it is out of support, you can't even download it any more).

Therefore, you could install a virtual machine on Mac, put Windows OS onto it, download and install 11gXE along with SQL Developer and use it.

But, why bother? Install VirtualBox and then download one of [Pre-Built Developer VMs (for Oracle VM VirtualBox)](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html).